# Get all products instead of a specific category?

Tags: product

I use the following code to get products of specific category:

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id)
 ->getProductCollection()
 ->addAttributeToSelect('*') // add all attributes - optional
 ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1) // enabled
 ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4) //visibility in catalog,search
 ->setOrder('price', 'ASC'); //sets the order by price
```

But how can I obtain all products instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code below:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
foreach($collection as $product) {
    echo $product->getId();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use magento object to filter.

Example:

```
$categoryId = 123; // a category id that you can get from admin
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addCategoryFilter($category)
    ->load();

print_r($products);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
   $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
foreach ($collection as $product) {

    $data = $product->getData();
    foreach ($data as $d)
        var_dump($d);

}
```